# How do I mask a height based fog?

Tags: shaders, fog-of-war, fog

I've been trying to implement a 3D (with the Y axis being utilized) fog of war system similar to what XCOM uses.

[image]
[image]
[image]

There is only one hint that really seems to nail it, but I can't read the actual function that was in place.

http://etiennecarrier.com/zombie-tycoon-2-fog-of-war-shader/

The key difference here is that I'm also trying to apply this to a multi leveled building.

So the question is... How do you go about implementing a height based fog shader, with a masking texture to prevent it from drawing in certain world spaces.

Comment: I already figured it out. You can just project the fog of war map over the geometry, and out put the result to a stencil buffer. That will mask the results.

Comment: if you're still around, it would be great if you'd post an Answer here detailing the solution you found.

Comment: @DMGregory Hard to explain. But I got the solution. Instead of projecting the mask, I use a bit of math to solve for the positions in the textures for each raymarch. This makes things less complicated in the end.